# angular js filter with ng-repeat not working until full text match

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi have used filter with ng-repeat to search records
like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.records | filter:search"></tr>
```

filter is only worked when whole text match like I have records
user1,user,test1,test2 if i type u or t only it is not showing any result and if I type user1 then it matched record

please suggest me any idea
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share records array?

Comment: it coming from API I have just given sample of array like [{name:'user1'},{name:'user2'},{name:'user3'},{name:'test1'}]

Comment: filter code looks fine,  ng-repeat is working fine?

Comment: yes ng-repeat working fine

Comment: then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Check this might be helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl as vm">
    <input ng-model="name">
    </br>
    </br>
    Filter All Field
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in vm.names | filter : name">
            {{ x.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    Filter Specific Field
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in vm.names | filter : {name:name}">
            {{ x.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function ($scope) {
        this.names = [{
            name: 'user1',
            last: 'last1'
        }, {
            name: 'user2',
            last: 'last1'
        }, {
            name: 'user3',
            last: 'last3'
        }, {
            name: 'test1',
            last: 'last4'
        }];
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example should be working with a single letter match. If you type **u** it will show `user1` and `user2`, if you type **t** it will show `test1` and `test2`:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
  this.records = [
    { name: 'user1' }, 
    { name: 'user2' }, 
    { name: 'test1' }, 
    { name: 'test2' }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in vm.records | filter:search">
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working plnkr

http://embed.plnkr.co/Oza8cb4sz32g8QOSCWqT/

Ignore the HTML.
There's no problem in the ng-repeat or the filter model. You need to change the structure of the binding declaration.

Please try to post full code. Cheers!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19080979)

Comment: @Paul - I've edited the answer. Sorry new to the system!

Comment: @sagars01 Your link should only be there as a reference. The goal is to have a valid answer, even if the link would not be there. This prevent's people from having to click through, but more importantly, if the link does not work anymore or it has been changed for whatever reason, your answer will still be valuable. For more information see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 0):

Please share your `vm.records` array withing object so you should try with
`<tr ng-repeat="data of vm.records | filter:search"></tr>`

please show below example may be helpful to you
[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XklvXtc1AZpndjLvXrh8?p=preview)